Count files in a directories AND create NEW folders based on that number
I have several directories that all have files in them.  I want to count the number of files and then create subdirectories based on that count.
Example 1:
Main Directory
+-> Subdirectory
    +-> file1
    +-> file2

In this case I would want to create Directory1 and Directory2
Example 2:
Main Directory
+-> Subdirectory
    +-> file1
    +-> file2
    +-> file3
    +-> file4

In this case I would want to create Directory1, Directory2, Directory3 and Directory4.

Where should Directory1, etc. be created?

for x in Main\ Directory/Subdirectory/*; do
    mkdir "Directory$(( ++i ))"
done


You may want to add some explanation how your script works ...

does this need to go into a bash script or can I just run the command directly from the command line?
